Relation between Hardy space and Smirnov class
I am studying about Hardy spaces on the disc and found a definition of the Smirnov class as
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{N^+}:= \{ f/g ; f,g\in H^\infty, g \text{ is an outer function} \}.
\end{align*}
I am now wondering about the relation between, let's say $H^2$ and $N^+$. Since there is an inner outer factorization for $H^2$, the only part of that might not be bounded is the outer part, is that correct? Specifically, I am wondering if the quotient of two outer functions is in $N^+$. Is that correct or are there maybe some restrictions to make that statement true? Because if so, then any outer function would be in $N^+$ because it can be written as 1 divided by an outer function. I also found a definition of the class $N^+$ as
\begin{align*}
\{F/G; F,G \in H^2, G\text{ is an outer function } \}.
\end{align*}
Are these two definitions the same? I would appreciate it if someone could awnser the specific question or direct me to some literature.

Any outer function is a ratio of bounded outer functions (and has no zeroes by definition) so its reciprocal is same (outer and ratio of bounded functions)

can you eloberate on that first statement? do you have a reference?

look at the definition of an outer function and decompose the boundary function into the part bigger than $1$ and between $0$ and $1$; as reference the book by Rosenblum and Rovnyak (Topics in Hardy Classes and Univalent Functions) has this done explicitly in the Lemma on page $56$ - see https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-0348-8520-1

that really helped me a lot, thank you :)
